# About RORO pattern performance

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

I'm so curious that using RORO pattern is evil in some cases in terms of memory consumption.

```js
function findUsersByRole ({  role,   withContactInfo,   includeInactive}) {...}
```

instead of

```js
function findUsersByRole (  role,   withContactInfo,   includeInactive) {...}
```

It seems obvious that when the first function is called, an object would be created and the object occupies space in memory.

I tried to check my assumption but I didn't get any clear difference. It appeared to be almost the same.

Here is my code using `@airbnb/node-memwatch`:

```js
const
memwatch = require('@airbnb/node-memwatch');
url = require('url');

function roro({a, b}) {
        console.log(a, b);
}

function nonRoro(a, b) {
        console.log(a, b);
}

memwatch.gc();

function roroBenchmark() {
var hd = new memwatch.HeapDiff();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        roro({a: 1, b: 2});
}

var hde = hd.end();

console.log(JSON.stringify(hde, null, 2));
}


function nonRoroBenchmark() {
var hd = new memwatch.HeapDiff();

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        nonRoro(1, 2);
}

var hde = hd.end();

console.log(JSON.stringify(hde, null, 2));
}


//roroBenchmark();
nonRoroBenchmark();
```

Is there any suggestion to verify my assumption?

Comment: It seems you already *did* test your assumption and found no difference. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for an unclear question. What I want to get is that RORO pattern is just ok to use in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: Yes, obviously it is, as your tests prove. Engines optimise short-lived objects quite well.